# How to replace the "" in "Hello" with .replace()?

Tags: typescript, replace

This only replaces the first ", but not the one at the end of a word

```
partFormatted = partFormatted.replace("\"", "");
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what programming language you are using.
Also, it would help if you wrote the contents of partFormatted before attempting to replace the characters.

Comment: Hi, sorry, Im using Typescript, the content is "hello"

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-do-i-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: I cant find an answer for the '""'

Comment: What do you mean can't find an answer? Use `replaceAll` instead of `replace` like the duplicate says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something I didn't see in the other post is using a regular expression.
Specifically the global flag.

`partFormatted = partFormatted.replace(/"/g, "");`

The 'g' indicates it should find all given matches and replace with given input